# S3 callbacks get ignored

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload a base64 encoded image to S3 through this route, but the callbacks get completely ignored and the code jumps straight to `res.json("SUCCESS");`

route

```
AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  secetAccessKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  region: "us-east-1"
});
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

....


router.post("/imageupload", async (req, res) => {

  const base64 = req.body.base64;
  try {
    const params = {
      Bucket: process.env.bucketName,
      Key: "images/newImage",
      Body: base64
    };

    await s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) res.json(err);
      else res.json(data);
    });
    res.json("SUCCESS");
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
    res.status(500).json(e.message);
  }
});
```

Any help is much appreciated thanks!

EDIT FIXED:
I figured out what the problem was:
I had recently reformatted my computer which meant I had to reinstall AWS cli AND reconfigure aws creds.
That was it.

Comment: This won't work. You can't have a callback with an `await`. You also can't have 2 responses that you send to the client in the way you are doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [AWS documentation for using-promises](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/using-promises.html).

```
var s3 = new AWS.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01', region: 'us-west-2'});
var params = {
  Bucket: 'bucket',
  Key: 'example2.txt',
  Body: 'Uploaded text using the promise-based method!'
};
var putObjectPromise = s3.putObject(params).promise();
putObjectPromise.then(function(data) {
  console.log('Success');
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

You can also promisify all functions by using a library such as bluebird

```
AWS.config.setPromisesDependency(require('bluebird'));
```

Here's an example using your code

```
router.post("/imageupload", async (req, res) => {

    const base64 = req.body.base64;
    try {
      const params = {
        Bucket: process.env.bucketName,
        Key: "images/newImage",
        Body: base64
      };

      const data = await s3.putObject(params).promise()
      res.json(data);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e.message);
      res.status(500).json(e.message);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Tried what you said but still not working. Callbacks still getting ignored and the console logs aren't getting printed out either.

Comment: I added an example using your code sample in my edit. ** You should not mix async/await and callbacks **.

Comment: Thanks, but now the curl request just hangs after I make it.  Do you know what else might be the issue?

Comment: I saw that you updated your post to say that you found the answer. Do you need anymore help?